# How can I properly create a dynamic table in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a dynamic table using data from a loop. I have written my code correctly and I get all the needed values from the loop but the table displays incorrectly. The headings are coming one after the other instead of in a single header field. I am trying to achieve something similar to the picture below [image]

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
let primeNumberArray = [];
form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  let startValue = parseInt(document.querySelector('.start').value);
  let endValue = parseInt(document.querySelector('.end').value);
  for (let i = startValue; i <= endValue; i++) {
    let flag = 0;
    
    // looping through 2 to user input number
    for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    // if number greater than 1 and not divisible by other numbers
    if (i > 1 && flag == 0) {
        primeNumberArray.push(i);
    }
}
let uniqueArray = [...new Set(primeNumberArray)]
 buildTable(uniqueArray);
})
//create table dynamically
function buildTable(data){
  let table = document.querySelector('.table');
  let output = '';
  for(let i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
    output += '<tr>'
    for(let j = 0; j<data.length; j++){
    output += '<td>' + data[i] * data[j]  + '</td>'     
    } 
    output+='</tr>'
  }
  table.innerHTML=output
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <label for="">Enter the First Number</label>
  <input class="start" type="number"><br>
  <label for="">Enter any Number to get the Multiplication table down to that number</label>
  <input class="end" type="number"><br>
  <button type="submit">Show Multiplication Table</button>
</form>

<table class="table">
</table>
```

Comment: The table should show prime numbers multiplication table?
It seems to miss a bit...
And you want the top and left to be headers?

Comment: Where is your code for the headers?
Are you sure your `data` is good?

Comment: For one thing, in the function that is adding an event listen to form, `formParent.insertBefore(table, form.nextSibling);`, you are trying to reference `table` which is not defined in that context/scope.

Comment: I checked from `1` to `100`, and it gave me: `primeNumberArray: [3, 5, 7, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]` = something is not right.

Comment: @iAmOren. It works now but I can't get the headers out of the code. It only shows the multiplication table.

Comment: I also noticed you are skipping `1` even if I enter it: I think `1` is a prime number...

Comment: Before showing the table, show the primes preceded by a blank `td`,
Then, precede each row with the row's prime.

Comment: @iAmOren 1 is not a prime number. I did that before but it looks horrible. I want to show the primes on the header and the first column.

Comment: I've finally finished my code: see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my sulution:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let startValue = parseInt(document.querySelector('.start').value);
  let endValue = parseInt(document.querySelector('.end').value);
  
  let primes=[];
  for(let i=Math.max(2, startValue); i<=endValue; i++) {
    let prime=true;
    for(let j=2; j<=Math.sqrt(i) && prime; j++) {
      prime=i%j;
    }
    if(prime) primes.push(i);
  }
  
  let table=document.createElement("table");
  table.classList.add("table");
  let tr=document.createElement("tr");
  tr.classList.add("dark");
  let td=document.createElement("td");
  td.classList.add("td");
  tr.append(td);
  for(let col=0; col<primes.length; col++) {
    td=document.createElement("td");
    td.classList.add("td");
    td.textContent=primes[col];
    tr.append(td);
  }
  table.append(tr);
  for(let row=0; row<primes.length; row++) {
    tr=document.createElement("tr");
    tr.classList.add((row%2)?"dark":"light");
    td=document.createElement("td");
    td.classList.add("td");
    td.textContent=primes[row];
    tr.append(td);
    for(let col=0; col<primes.length; col++) {
      td=document.createElement("td");
      td.classList.add("td");
      td.textContent=primes[row]*primes[col];
      tr.append(td);
    }
    table.append(tr);
  }
  
  let tableDiv = document.querySelector('.tableDiv');
  if(tableDiv.children.length) tableDiv.replaceChild(table, tableDiv.childNodes[0]);
  else tableDiv.append(table);
});
```

```css
.table, .td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

.dark {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.light {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <table>
    <tr><td colspan=2 align=center>Prime numbers multiplication table:</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=center><label for="">From</label></td>
      <td align=center><input class="start" type="number"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=center><label for="">To</label></td>
      <td align=center><input class="end" type="number"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td align=center><button type="submit">Show Multiplication Table</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form><br>
<div class="tableDiv"></div>
```

I've use a different prime finder, and
Used a `div` to "host" the `table`.

Comment: Thank you. This is so easy for me to understand.

Comment: My pleasure!
It makes me happy to be reassured that I'm understood.

Comment: I used to create HTML text and set the `innerHTML` = I was "afraid" of `createElement`, but, since I've started using it = I can't remember what was so "scary"... :)

Answer (score 0):

You should separate data from presentation.

1. Generate all the primes in the range
2. Create a matrix by multiplying the primes
3. Wrap the matrix in col/row headers
4. Format wrapped-matrix as a table
5. Style as-needed

```js
const main = () => {
  document.body.appendChild(createPrimeMultiplicationTable(7, 31))
};

const createPrimeMultiplicationTable = (min, max) =>
  (primes =>
    matrixToTable(wrapMatrix(generateMatrixFromIterable(primes,
        (col, row) => col * row), {
      colHeaderFn: index => primes[index],
      rowHeaderFn: index => primes[index]
    })))
  (generatePrimes(min, max));

/* === Helpers === */

const generateMatrixFromIterable = (iterable, cellFn) =>
  iterable.map(row => iterable.map(col => cellFn(col, row)));

const generateMatrix = (rows, cols, cellFn) =>
  range(rows).map(row => range(cols).map(col => cellFn(col, row)));

const wrapMatrix = (matrix, opts) => [
  [
    null,
    ...range(matrix[0].length).map(index =>
      opts.colHeaderFn(index))
  ],
  ...matrix.map((row, index) => [
    opts.rowHeaderFn(index),
    ...row
  ])
];

/* === Utils === */

const matrixToTable = (matrix) =>
  createEl('table', {
    children: matrix.map(row => createEl('tr', {
      children: row.map(col => createEl('td', {
        text: col
      }))
    }))
  });

const generatePrimes = (min, max) => {
  const primes = [];
  let numbers = [];
  for (let i = 2; i <= max; i++) numbers.push(i);
  while (numbers.length) {
    primes.push(numbers.shift());
    numbers = numbers.filter(n => n % primes[primes.length - 1] != 0);
  }
  return primes.filter(n => n >= min);
}

const range = (size) => new Array(size).fill(0).map((_, index) => index);

const createEl = (tagName, opts) => {
  const el = document.createElement(tagName);
  if (opts.text) el.textContent = opts.text;
  if (opts.children) opts.children.forEach(child =>
    el.appendChild(child));
  return el;
}

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
td {
  border: thin solid grey;
}

td {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.25em;
  text-align: right;
}

tr:first-child td {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #DDD;
}

td:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #DDD;
}
```